# How do I use TypeScript's compiled output in a browser as simply as possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been porting a JS game to TypeScript, and upon my first trial (of a portion of the port), I am finding that the compiled output of TypeScript doesn't run in a browser!

What is the minimal work-flow for getting TypeScript's output to run in a browser? Full, cross-browser support not required for the moment.

EDIT: Sorry for lack of detail. I'm testing in Firefox 57.0 and the error I get is "defined is not defined". I googled this and was pointed to RequireJs, which I employed, but did not solve this problem. I just tested in Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 and the same error appears. Here is my test html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>TypeScript Greeter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="target/stinkum2.generated.js"></script>
        <script data-main="scripts/app" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run"? What error are you getting?

Comment: What browser? How are you generating it?

Comment: For the moment, compile it with a target of ES6 with ES Modules, and run it in Chrome 61+.

That should work.

Comment: What do you mean by minimal workflow ? I would suggest not using modules, that greatly simplifies the workflow if you’re just getting to grips with the basics!

Comment: By minimal, I mean, run tsc, use that output in html <script>, and see program run. Now, by modules do you mean "module" in tsconfig? Or modules, like namespaces, within the code? If the latter, let me add that I am not using any. All I have so far is basic classes, import lines at the top of the files (e.g. import { blah } from 'thing' ). in my tsconfig i use module == amd or system just because i want the concatenated 'outFile'. Please help!